# Loading KML file from URL and adding to a map (Kotlin, Android)

Tags: android, url, kotlin, kml

Simple yet so annoying!

So, I've been trying to load a KML file from an web URL and I just can't get it to work.
I made a map and it shows.
I tried to load the kml file locally and it works fine.

The thing is the KML file will update from now and then and thats why I need it online.

With IOS it works fine and the KML is accessible from anywhere

Thank You for Your answers!

```
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
            map = googleMap
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location))
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 14.0F))
            map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID
            enableMyLocation()
            val layer = KmlLayer(map, R.raw.kmlMap, activity as MainActivity)
            layer.addLayerToMap()

        }
```

The R.raw file is locally and it works fine, as soon as i want to put an input stream I cant get it to work. I'm using the official Google KML developing util: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml

Comment: Any news on that?